# RViz Ignoring Collisions Between Attached Object and Environment

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, collision-object

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have, from what I can tell, successfully attached a mesh to my robot via this [tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/src/doc/planning_scene_ros_api_tutorial.html), however the collision checking in RViz seems wrong.

After attaching the added object (previously green) turns purple.  By dragging the goal state query around I confirm that the attached object collides correctly with the robot **but NOT with other objects in the environment** (the robot, however, will collide with said objects).  I tried searching for this issue and found some other related topics but none with my exact situation.

Some notes:

- The attached object is not visible on RViz's goal query until I hit the "Publish Current Scene" button
- Visualizations via the "/move_group/display_planned_path" do not show the attached object

[edit]
Playing some more with RViz I am getting status messages to the effect of:

```
Goal state colliding links:
attached_object - environment_object
```

but the robot doesn't turn any links red and/or cycle through solutions looking for a "good" solution.  It is also more than happy to plan and execute to that goal state with colliding links...

What am I missing here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248071/rviz-ignoring-collisions-between-attached-object-and-environment/) by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 525 on 2016-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you build MoveIt! from source?
This sounds to me like you might hit https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/191 which is not fully released yet.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2016-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2016-11-14**:
Score; this solved the issue. Thanks for the quick reply v4hn.

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2017-01-26**:
Is this issue fixed and has it been released?

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-01-26**:
Yes, this is officially released in all ros-distributions.

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2017-01-26**:
@v4hn I was having the same issue and as a workaround I tried attaching the object to a link with collision geometry. But I still see collision in between the attached object and the environment. Any hints on what the issue might be?